# If $f''(x) = 1-2x$ , $f'(0) = -1$ and $f(0) = 2$. Find $f(x)$.

Tags: integration, derivatives

I tried to find $f'(x)$ using $f''(x)$, and found that $f'(x)=  x - x^2  + C$. From that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: **Hint:** How about using $f'(0)$ to find $ C$ and then integrating again and using the other IC to find $f(x)$?

Comment: @Moo Was `IC` as `Initial Condition` ? :-)

Comment: @Mikasa: Correct.

Answer (score 3):

As you found, $f'(x) = x-x^2+C$
\begin{equation}
f'(0) = -1 = 0 -0^2+C \Rightarrow C = -1
\end{equation}

Repeat the same process for $f(x)$, you'll get $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3} - x + C_1$
\begin{equation}
f(0) = 2 = 0 - 0 - 0 + C_1 \Rightarrow C_1 = 2 \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3} - x + 2
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$$f^{(3)}(x)=-2$$
Taylor formula gives

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2}f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(0)$$

$$=2-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$$